# react apexcharts marker color

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, charts, apexcharts

I using Apexcharts for my project but I have a problem with change color of marker if value is negative number `<0`

The value is show by Y axis.

This is my logic

```
 const chartData = this.state.data;  //the output is [1,3,2-5,-7,5,9,-2]

        const chartSeries = [
            {
                name: 'Data1',
                data: chartData
            },
        ];

        const seriesData = chartData.flatMap((value, index) => ({
            x: index,
            y: value, 
            fillColor: value >= 0 ? '#0000ff' : '#ff0000',
        }));

const Options: ApexOptions = {
markers: {
                size: 2,
                colors: seriesData.map((data) => data.fillColor), 
                strokeWidth: 0,
                hover: {
                    size: 3,
                },
            },
}
```

This code make output `#0000ff` for both positive and negative values.

Where is my mistake in this code?

Comment: I'm not find solution yet